# How do I use Gitlab variables with SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe inside of a gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: .net, msbuild, sonarqube, gitlab, sonarqube-scan

When i try to use SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe with switches like:

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe /k:%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME% /n:%CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%
```

The log dump gives me problems for having %CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME%. It's as if they don't exist or that they can't be found.

I also see this line at the end of the file:

```
'GitLab Commit Issue Publisher' skipped because one of the required properties is missing
```

Here is my SonarQube.Analysis.xml file

```
<SonarQubeAnalysisProperties  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.sonarsource.com/msbuild/integration/2015/1">
 <!-- The sonarqube server address -->
  <Property Name="sonar.host.url">http://server.com:1234</Property>

      <Property Name="sonar.sourceEncoding">UTF-8</Property>      

      <!-- I have no idea if anything below this line works -->
    <!--   <Property Name="sonar.projectName">Master</Property>  Should be set in job of the gitlab yml
      <Property Name="sonar.projectKey">Master</Property> Should be set in job of the gitlab yml -->
      <Property Name="sonar.exclusions">folder\**</Property>
      <Property Name="sonar.sources">.</Property>
      <Property Name="sonar.verbose">true</Property>
     <!--  <Property Name="sonar.scanner.dumpToFile">somethingWentWrong.txt</Property> -->
      <Property Name="sonar.analysis.mode">issues</Property>


      <!--
    this is only for forced authentication. the group "everyone" on the server has execute permission so you don't need to fill this out.
      <Property Name="sonar.login"></Property>
      <Property Name="sonar.password"></Property>
      -->


    </SonarQubeAnalysisProperties>
```

here is the command sequence I use to call SonarQube.Scanner.MSbuild.exe in the gitlab-ci.yml job:

```
 - SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:doesthiswork /n:doesthiswork 
 - MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild directory\Solution.sln
 - SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

What do I not understand about using Gitlab predfined variables in SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe calls inside of Gitlab-ci.yml?

gitlab variables: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#predefined-variables-environment-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab and sonarqube variables can be used; but they can't be referenced from inside gitlab-ci.yml.

In gitlab-ci.yml make a call to a batch script such as:

```
   - cmd.exe /c callMyBatch.bat
```

....inside of callMyBatch.bat

```
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:%GITLABORENVIRONMENTVAR% 
MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild directory\Solution.sln
SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```